# DateTimePicker UI - restricting time picker end to be after start

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have a start time and an end time input box, box making use of the time picker extension for datetimepicker-UI.

I'm trying to make to so that the finish time cannot be earlier than the start time but so far all my configuration options have failed.

This is my attempt using the sample from the site:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#theDate" ).datepicker({
        minDate: -0,
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "/assets/img/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy "

    });
    //Time pickers
    $("#startTime").timepicker({
        //increment in 10mins
        //can't be sooner than now.
        controlType: 'select',
        oneLine: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
    });


    $("#endTime").timepicker({
        //need to set the range to be AFTER startTime
        controlType: 'select',
        oneLine: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
    });

    var $minimumStartTime = $("startTime").val();
    var $minimumEndTime = $("endTime").val();

    $.timepicker.timeRange(
            $minimumStartTime,
            $minimumEndTime,
            {
                minInterval: (1000*60*60), // 1hr
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                start: {}, // start picker options
                end: {} // end picker options
            }
    )


});
```

It's inclusive of my datePicker too which is working fine.

Any help is hugely appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just using the `minTime` option? The usual way is to attach a setter to a select event. [There's even an example in the documentation page](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#range_examples) doing exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic functionality of a working datepicker minDate of another datepickers value: http://jsfiddle.net/w0hgkzqf/

```
$('input.start').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, obj) {
        $('input.end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
    }
});
$('input.end').datepicker();
```

Comment: Thank you. When I get home I'll try and apply the same logic to the time picker.